# how to insert SQL query inside string

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have these two queries.

1. `to_char(to_date('1970-01-01 **1:00:00**', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:MI:SS') + NET_START.STARTPROC/1000/60/60/24, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:MI:SS') as STARTPROC;`
2. `SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr') FROM dual`

query 2 returns a string that contains 1:00:00 and i would like to use that query inside query 1 to replace the highlighted 1:00:00.

something like this

`to_char(to_date('1970-01-01    (SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr') FROM dual)’, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:MI:SS') + NET_START.STARTPROC/1000/60/60/24, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:MI:SS') as STARTPROC`

Answer (score 1):

Oracle use `||` to connect string

```
to_date('1970-01-01'||(SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr') FROM dual), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:MI:SS')
```

try this.

Comment: Should be `'1970-01-01 '`  (with a blank)

Comment: oops. that is a typo. but I'm pretty sure OP will get what those mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `||` operator without query as follows:

```
to_char(to_date('1970-01-01 ' || TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr') , 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:MI:SS') 
+ NET_START.STARTPROC/1000/60/60/24, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:MI:SS') as STARTPROC;
```